# How to query for the count of string appearances with the same id in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say I have a table like such:

```
client_id  |        description
----------------------------------------
      0    |      blah soccer blah     |
      0    |      blah blah  soccer    | 
      2    |      blah blah            |
      0    |      soccer blah  blah    |
      1    |      blah blah            |
      2    |      blah blah  soccer    |
```

I want to query for the count of descriptions that contain the word soccer and that have the same client_id. The output for the above example would be:

```
client_id  |   count
------------------------
      0    |      3    |
      2    |      1    |
```

The word "soccer" appeared 3 times where the client_id=0 and once when the client_id=2

I have tried using sub-queries, but i am not able to achieve this exact example. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple count with an aggregation.

```sql
select
  client_id
  , count(*) as cnt
from 
  my_table
where
  /* the lower function is used here to ensure we are grabbing 
     variations of the same word such as Soccer and SoCceR 
  */
  lower(description) like '%soccer%'
group by
  /* this gives us the above count grouped to the client_id
     if we wanted to know something like city then client_id, we
     could add city before client_id in both the select and group by
     clauses
  */
  client_id
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is conditional aggrewgation

```
select client_id,
       count(*) filter (where description like '%soccer%') as num_soccer
from t
group by client_id;
```